# Why doesn't the function in the Aiogram FSM work?

Tags: python, aiogram

I need help, I want to make my function work in the state machine. When I run the code, it gets to the moment "Enter to check:". I enter and nothing happens. Without a state machine, everything works, I want the function to accept the text of the message and then process it and display the result. Thanks in advance!

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp, bot
from func import function # this function itself
from keyboard import func_kb


async def start_command(message : types.Message):
   await message.answer("Greetings! Select the function you need.", reply_markup=func_kb)


class Form(StatesGroup):
   seturl = State()



@dp.message_handler(commands=['Test'])
   async def test(message: types.Message):
   await message.reply('Enter to check:')
   await Form.seturl.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.seturl)
async def monet(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):

   get_result = function(message.text) #get value from function

   if get_result == "true":
       await message.answer("Yes")
   else:
       await message.answer('Not')

   await state.finish()
    
  
def register_handlers(dp : Dispatcher):
     dp.register_message_handler(start_command, commands=['start'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code locally and it worked for me. I can assume that you did not initialize the handlers or did it incorrectly. Either `function` returns nothing, or it returns, but not boolean values.

And I also noticed that you have "true" written in the if statement, if your `function` returns `return True or False`, then most likely this is an error. You need to write like this:

```
if get_result:
    await message.answer("Yes")
else:
   await message.answer('Not')
```